# If $E \lvert X_1 \rvert = \infty$, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(\lvert X_1 \rvert > a_n) <\infty $and $a_n/n$ increase, then $a_n/n \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I want to prove followings:

> If $E \lvert X_1 \rvert = \infty$, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(\lvert X_1 \rvert > a_n) <\infty $and $a_n/n$ increase, then $a_n/n \rightarrow \infty$

It's described in Durrett's *Probability theory and examples (5th ed)* Thm 2.5.13
He said its obvious, but how can I prove it?
Could you explain details of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $\frac {a_n} n$ increase to a finite number $C$. Then $a_n <2C n$ for $n$ sufficiently large. Hence $P(|X_1| >a_n) \geq P(|X_1|>2Cn)$ for such $n$. It follows that $\sum P(|X| >n) <\infty$, where $X=\frac {X_1 } {2C}$. But this implies that $E|X| <\infty$ and hence $E|X_1| <\infty$.

I have assumed the following well known fact: $E|X| <\infty$ iff $\sum P(|X| >n) <\infty$. You can find  a proof of this on this site as well as ion Wikipedia.

Comment: Thank you for your kindness. It's very helpful!